# How to echo html in php with link to database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, twitter-bootstrap

below is what i had tried:

```
echo "<input class='form-control' type='text' name='jobID'  value='.$result['jobID'].' readonly>";
```

or

```
echo "<input class='form-control' type='text' name='jobID'  value=<?php $result['jobID'];?>readonly>";
```

thank you so much

Comment: can you try to explain a bit more what it is you are trying to do?

Comment: not need to use `<?php` because u already inside php

Comment: @waniryu did you got what I am trying to say in my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> HTML IN PHP

```
 echo "<input class='form-control' type='text' name='jobID'  value='".$result['jobID'];."'readonly />";
```

> PHP IN HTML

```
<input class='form-control' type='text' name='jobID'  value='<?php echo $result['jobID']; ?>' readonly />
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use " " you dont need the point, so the code is :

```
$variable= $result['jobID'];   
echo "<input class='form-control' type='text' name='jobID'  value='$variable' readonly>";
```